# Docker Container: time/timezone wrong

Tags: time, docker, timezone, system, systemtime

I am in a running docker container with node and for some reason the timezones / the time of the host machine vs inside the docker container never line up:

```
root@foobar:~# node -e "console.log(new Date())"
>> Tue May 17 2016 15:12:43 GMT+0200 (CEST)
root@foobar:~# docker exec 9179105c0ff9 node -e "console.log(new Date())"
>> Tue May 17 2016 13:13:01 GMT+0000 (Europe)
root@foobar:~# cat /etc/timezone
>> Europe/Vienna
root@foobar:~# docker exec 9179105c0ff9 cat /etc/timezone
>> Europe/Vienna
```

So what I already did in my docker-start shell is script is the following:

```
docker run \
...
-v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro \
-v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro \
-e "TZ=Europe/Vienna" \
...
```

... but still, as you can see in the first codeblock, the time is still wrong! Any ideas on this? What am I missing?

(fyi: I am running a meteor app deployed via [mupx](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx))

**UPDATE:**

After running `date` on the host and inside the container, there again is a difference of 2hrs. so for some reason the docker container just does not "apply" my timezone and **it seems like the problem is not JS/node related, since `date`is just a simple unix system cmd** ... what am I missing here?!

Comment: There is an answer on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/a/683651

Answer (score 2):

`>> Tue May 17 2016 15:12:43 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

and

`>> Tue May 17 2016 13:13:01 GMT+0000 (Europe)`

are approximately the same time(around 18sec difference, because you didn't ran the commands at the same time).
Take a closer look, it's around 3pm GMT+0200 and around 1pm GMT+0000.
This is just a difference in output format, but the time is the same.
If you execute `.getTime()` on the value of the `new Date()`, you will probably have the same values.
This is probably due to differences in default output format in different node.js versions.

Comment: I do realize it is "the same" time. But the node versions are the same on the host and inside the container. Also, when I use `date` to just echo the system time, there is the 2hrs difference again between the container and the host. and since `date` is not a JS function or anything but just unix related, this seems to actually not be a JS issue after all.

Comment: Strange thing, what I have locally: 
`$ date ; TZ="Europe/Vienna" date ;  docker run node date ; docker run -e TZ="Europe/Vienna" node date 
Tue May 17 15:54:07 UTC 2016
Tue May 17 17:54:07 CEST 2016
Tue May 17 15:54:08 UTC 2016
Tue May 17 17:54:09 CEST 2016`

Comment: I have this locally : 
`docker run -e TZ="Europe/Vienna" node node -e "console.log(new Date().getTimezoneOffset())"` => -120
`docker run node node -e "console.log(new Date().getTimezoneOffset())"` => 0 , that is, docker, the docker image I'm using and node are honoring the TZ variable. What docker image are you using ? Can you get the TZ variable with running `/usr/bin/env` in your image ?

Answer (score 0):

I do it in this way:
args: ["-v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro","-v /etc/localtime:/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Prague:ro", '-e TZ=Europe/Prague']

Need to install timedatectl

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised to see the same problem when using new Date().toString() in a container. It always returns the string for GMT+000, and not for the server's time zone. There might be container-specific settings to change the time zone, but since I know my time zone - New York, I just used toLocaleString:
new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})

Answer (score 0):

```js
function adjustTimestampWithTimezone(timestamp) {
    let timestampInMillis = new Date(timestamp).getTime();
  
    // Get the timezone offset in minutes and convert it to milliseconds
    let timezoneOffsetInMillis = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;  
    // Calculate the adjusted timestamp with timezone
    let adjustedTimestamp = (timestampInMillis - timezoneOffsetInMillis) / 1000;
  
    return parseInt(adjustedTimestamp);
  }
```

use this function which is independent of docker environment, you can maintain consistent across the application.